# Is it possible to use glycerol DNA/RNA drying during extraction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, chemical-biology

Is it possible to use glycerol with ethanol in order to avoid over-drying of DNA/RNA at drying step of extraction protocol?

Comment: Glycerol is likely to prevent the evaporation of ethanol.

Answer (score 1):

if glycerol residues stay in DNA, it might interact with later PCR. Overdrying is an underestimated issue and often DNA resuspension is not only long (>3h) but also very partial even after one night resuspension. it is not possible to evaporate ethanol first but reaching the point where sample are still wet but ethanol mostly removed is the best option